# Laravel Search Condition Problem. When condition is value empty, then go to else condition. But it's not work properly

Tags: laravel

This is my search code please see then solution, thank you.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! **[We discourage screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)**. You are making it harder to help you because we have to retype your data or code 

Comment: What field types are you using for `date` and `month` in your database? Also, is there a reason you don't simply have a single date field?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use like this

```
$report_ex = Expenses::where(condition)->where(condition)->get();
```

or

```
$report_ex = Expenses::where(condition)->where(condition)->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using

```
$report_ex = Expenses::where(condition)->where(condition)->first();
```

then you need to call

```
if(!empty($report_ex))
{
  // your code
}
else
{
  //your code
}
```

But if you are using

```
$report_ex = Expenses::where(condition)->where(condition)->get();
```

then you should use

```
if(count($report_ex) > 0)
{
// your code
}
else
{
// your code
}
```

since get function returns an empty object